# print first name + 5characters of last name in Java

Tags: java, printf

I'm attempting to get user input and print out the first name + 5 characters from the last name followed by random numbers. I'm really new to `Java` and I've been able to get user input and make the random number but I'm not quite sure how I should format the `printf` to only get 5 characters from my second string. I'm not even 100% sure `printf` is what I'm looking for.

```
Scanner name = new Scanner (System.in);

String firstname;
String secondname;
System.out.println("Enter your first name:");
firstname = name.next();
System.out.println("Enter your last name:");
secondname = name.next();
```

Is how I'm getting user input for their first and last name.

edit: I'm supposed to assume the last name has more than 5 characters

Comment: what if the last name has less than 5 characters?

Comment: Check out the Javadoc on the `String` class - the `substring()` method might help you out.

Comment: You should partition your problem and ask at irc://freenode/##java. It is evil to post useless questions at FAQ.

Comment: I'm sure `printf` would do what you want but frankly its so much easier to do `System.out.println("This " + returnIs() " so " + returnEasy());` unless you want something unusual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were looking to display *up to* five characters from the last name (`secondname`), you can use substring:

```
System.out.println(secondname.substring(0, Math.min(5, secondname.length())));
```

Therefore, your final output would be something like this:

```
// Import 'java.util.Random' at the top of your file

Random rand = new Random();
int max = 9999;
int min = 1000;
int rnd = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

String fullString = firstname
    + secondname.substring(0, Math.min(5, secondname.length()))
    + String.valueOf(rnd);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `String.substring` to get a portion of your `String`.

```
System.out.println(secondname.substring(0,5));
```

Remember to check the actual length first, otherwise you'll throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Also remember to check for `null`s.

Answer (score 1):

Something, like this:

```
String result = firstname + ((secondname.length() > 5) ? secondname.substring(0, 5) : secondname) + random;
```

This code checks secondname length, and if secondname is shorter than 5 chars, it will be appended fully. 
random - is your random number. 
result will contain exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick

```
    String secondname = "sdrias";
    String firstname = "rasdgfdsg";
    String combinedString = "";
    if(secondname.length() < 5) {
       combinedString = firstname+secondname;
    } else {
       combinedString = firstname+secondname.substring(0, 5);
    }

    System.out.println(combinedString);
```